# Best way to set tagged HTML as Tooltipster content

Tags: jquery, tooltipster

Tooltipster can take a string as content. For example,

```
var myHTML = "Hello world";
instance.content(myHTML);
```

But the content cannot include HTML tags. You can't use this

```
var myHTML = "Hello <i>world</i>";
```

although this

```
var myHTML = "Hello &lt;i&gt;world&lt;/i&gt;";
```

works.

What is the straightforward way to set a string of tagged HTML as the content of Toolstipster?

Comment: Have you set `contentAsHTML`?

Comment: Yes. Whatever is in the tags fails to appear as content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not Tooltipster. It was using Toolstipster with XHTML.

```
var myHTML = "Hello <i>world</i>";
instance.content(myHTML);
```

works just fine . . . in HTML but not in XHTML, as was being used here.

XHTML parses entities inside `<script>`. To stop that, wrap the script inside a CDATA:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

var myHTML = "Hello <i>world</i>";
instance.content(myHTML);

//]]>
</script>
```